# Error on Google HotTrend reader

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-api

i tried to get google [hot trend](http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends/atom/hourly) 
data using jquery. i wrote a code for that but it's returned error status code 0 could you please help me to find what's wrong with that?

here is my code

```
function topSearchesRss() {
    var url = 'http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends/atom/hourly';
    $.ajax({ type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        datatype: 'xml',
        error: function (err) { alert(err.status);},
        success: function (xml) { alert('sucesss'); }
    });
}
```